# Blender edited FBX model is not smooth when imported to Maya

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx

I edited an FBX model in Blender (mainly its vertex groups).  I exported it--all looked fine--but when I reimported that FBX file to Maya in order to further edit it, it was no longer smooth.  I've attached an image of part of the mesh.  It looks very triangulated.  I've tried many solutions:

[image: un-smooth mesh]

1. smoothing the mesh in Maya (not just smoothing the preview)
2. turning off custom split normals in Blender
3. removing doubles in Blender
4. flipping the normals

Nothing seems to work, but I may have improperly applied one of these fixes.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for any advice!

Comment:  help.  I can't seem to find any workable solution to this

Comment: I have the same problem, been pulling my hair trying to fix this, and could not find any way to get blender to expert smoothed normals, although they were shown smoothed before export. Exporting the same model in Obj works perfectly, but the FBX exporter has bugs. In the end I wrote a smoother routine that looks for groups of 5 matching vertex positions, then I sum and normalize all the normals, which works perfectly, but runs slow on large models. I´m also seeing bad UV coordinates on the FBX ecports, I´ll register these bugs, but any help would be appreciated.